# pass array of array in request post in python

Tags: python, request

I am used request in python. I try to sent a post request and need send array of array. This is my code:

```
import requests

def connecttomlapipost(url, vector):
   headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
   r= requests.post(url, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin'), data = vector, headers=headers)
   return r

print connecttomlapipost('https://......', [[2,3],[1,5]])
```

the server return: error 500. I tested using POSTMAN and the server return a correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `post` and are most likely interested in using `data` instead or `params`. It should be a dictionary structure instead of a list though. [See the docs.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: additionally **import json** and **data = json.dumps(vector)**